# Fetch specific rows from MySQL with datatables

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to fetch specific rows in a MySQL table with specific "basket_id"s and display them in the jQuery DataTables plugin.

In the PHP server-side script for the DataTables AJAX request, I specify the `$user->basketId()` in a WHERE clause for MySQL..

Let me walk you through it..

1. User signs in.
2. USER class stores user session data. (use public methods to retrieve data)
3. In dashboard user clicks ITEMS and sees a datatable.

The problem is that all users are seeing all items from all baskets.

I have verified that the `$user->basketId()` method return the correct basket ID for the user.

```php
<?php

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/init.php";

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$con = mysqli_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);

$output= array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE basket = ".$user->basketId()."";

$totalQuery = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$total_all_rows = mysqli_num_rows($totalQuery);

$columns = array(
    0 => 'id',
    1 => 'name',
    2 => 'photo',
    3 => 'quality',
    4 => 'locations',
    4 => 'suppliers',
);

if(isset($_GET['search']['value']))
{
    $search_value = $_GET['search']['value'];
    $sql .= " OR name like '%".$search_value."%'";
    $sql .= " OR quality like '%".$search_value."%'";
    $sql .= " OR locations like '%".$search_value."%'";
    $sql .= " OR suppliers like '%".$search_value."%'";
}

if(isset($_GET['order']))
{
    $column_name = $_GET['order'][0]['column'];
    $order = $_GET['order'][0]['dir'];
    $sql .= " ORDER BY ".$columns[$column_name]." ".$order."";
}
else
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY name desc";
}

if($_GET['length'] != -1)
{
    $start = $_GET['start'];
    $length = $_GET['length'];
    $sql .= " LIMIT  ".$start.", ".$length;
}   

$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $sub_array = array();
    $sub_array[] = $row['name'];
    $sub_array[] = '<img src="'.$config['app_url'].'includes/assets/img/item_photos/'.substr($row['photo'], strrpos($row['photo'], '/') + 1).'" class="img-fluid rounded-circle dt-img" alt="Item Photo">';
    $sub_array[] = $row['quality'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['locations'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['suppliers'];
    $sub_array[] = '<button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm update-class-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#update-class-modal" id="'.$row['id'].'" type="button"><span><i class="fad fa-pencil"></i></span></button> <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete-class" id="'.$row['id'].'" type="button"><span><i class="fad fa-trash"></i></span></button>';
    $data[] = $sub_array;
}

$output = array(
    'draw'=> intval($_GET['draw']),
    'recordsTotal' =>$count_rows ,
    'recordsFiltered'=>   $total_all_rows,
    'data'=>$data,
);

echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

I'm not sure why, but it doesn't matter which user I am logged into and which basket ID is returned, datatables always fetches all the items in the items table.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: Echo the `$sql` variable and look at the query you are running

Comment: Your query will be `WHERE basket = 99 OR name like OR xxx LIKE OR dd LIKE ...` So basically you are going to get almost everything

Comment: So you want to get it to `WHERE basket = 99 AND ( xxx LIKE 'ddd' OR yyy LIKE 'ddd' OR zzz....) ORDER BY ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after doing some researching using all the keywords I could think of I came up with an answer.

DataTables already provides an `SSP.php` library which is a Server-side Processing Class for PHP.

Using the SSP::complex() method we can define two extra conditions:

```php
SSP::complex( $request, $conn, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $whereResult=null, $whereAll=null )
```

1. `$whereResult=null`

This is a `WHERE` clause for data **AFTER** it has been fetched from the DB table, so this will filter through results after the SQL results are returned.

2. `$whereAll=null`

This is a `WHERE` clause for data **BEFORE** it has been fetched from the DB, so this will add a `WHERE` condition before the SQL query and will only return results that match.

After everything my final `get_items.php` AJAX file looks like

```php
<?php

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/init.php";
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

// Database connection info 
$dbDetails = array( 
    'host' => 'redacted', 
    'user' => 'redacted', 
    'pass' => 'redacted', 
    'db'   => 'redacted' 
); 
 
// DB table to use 
$table = 'items'; 
 
// Table's primary key 
$primaryKey = 'id'; 
 
// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. 
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database.  
// The `dt` parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. 
$columns = array( 
    array( 'db' => 'id',  'dt' => 0 ), 
    array( 'db' => 'name',      'dt' => 1 ), 
    array( 'db' => 'photo',     'dt' => 2 ), 
    array( 'db' => 'quality',    'dt' => 3 ), 
    array( 'db' => 'locations',    'dt' => 4 ),
    array( 'db' => 'suppliers', 'dt' => 5 )
);
 
// Output data as json format 
echo json_encode( 
    SSP::complex( $_GET, $dbDetails, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, null, "school = {$user->basketId()}" )
);
```